# Lost Samsung galaxy core in ocean

Tags: samsung

I dropped my phone in the ocean never got it back .can I recover any photos or contacts from it if I have ISDN ESN meid info

Comment: Is this a serious question?

Comment: How am I supposed to flag this? Is this even flaggable?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman 'Blatantly off-topic,' I guess.

Answer (score 4):

No... Unless you were backing up that information to a cloud service like Google Photo, then just log into that account, your phone information is of no use.

Otherwise the phone is at the bottom of the ocean... Unless you can physically recover it there is no chance of retrieving any information that was only stored on the device. Even if you recover it, the chances are still almost zero.